# Parsing CoDeSys .pro file

Tags: c#, parsing, codesys

I'm trying to parse a .pro file, but I get strange chars within the file.

```
    public List<string> GetTextBlocks(int minBlockSize = 10)
    {
        if (_TextBlocks != null && _TextBlocksMinBlockSize == minBlockSize)
            return _TextBlocks;

        StreamReader pro = new StreamReader(_FileName, Encoding.ASCII);
        List<string> Blocks = new List<string>(); 

        string Content = pro.ReadToEnd();
        StringBuilder CurrentBlock = new StringBuilder();

        for (int n = 0; n < Content.Length; n++)
        {
            int c = Content[n];
            if (char.IsControl((char)c) && c != 10 && c != 13 && c != 9)
            {
                if (CurrentBlock.Length >= minBlockSize)
                    Blocks.Add(CurrentBlock.ToString());
                CurrentBlock.Clear();
            }
            else
                CurrentBlock.Append((char)c);
        }

        _TextBlocks = Blocks;
        _TextBlocksMinBlockSize = minBlockSize;

        return Blocks;//TODO: Comment
    }
```

Anyone tried that before?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use:

```
Encoding.UTF7
```